# How would I make a Generator that generates 1 ____ every __ seconds in my run method without using Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, if-statement

Right now, this is the code that I have:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    init();

    int fps = 60;
    double timePerTick = 1000000000 / fps;
    double delta = 0;
    long now;
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long timer = 0;
    int ticks = 0;

    makeMaps();
    makeTeams();

    boolean madeIron = false, madeGold = false, madeDim = false, madeEm = false, madeRuby = false;

    while(running){
        if(madeIron == false && iron < 48) {
            madeIron = true;
            iron++;
        }
        //if(loops==(loops/5)*5) { I don't know how I would put something here that would set madeIron to false every ___ seconds
        //  
        //}
        loops++;
        now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / timePerTick;
        timer += now - lastTime;
        lastTime = now;

        if(delta >= 1) {
            if(random.nextInt(50)==random.nextInt(50)) {
                update();
            }
            render();
        }

        if(timer >= 1000000000){
            System.out.println("Ticks and Frames: " + ticks);
            ticks = 0;
            timer = 0;
        }
    }

    stop();
}
```

Would there be any way that I would be able to set `madeIron`, or any of the `made____`, every ____ seconds?
**Explaining the code:**
`init()` is the method where I initialize everything, right now all I have in it is the code to make the JFrame.
The next few lines, starting at `int fps` and ending at `int ticks` is how I make a specific fps for every computer; I can change `int fps`'s value to whatever I want and the other code will make up for it.
The two `make()`s are how I make the maps and the teams for my game.
The `boolean`s are how, in the future, I will make a Generator for each island on each map.
There's then the `while(running)` loop.
After that is how I test if I need to increment my iron.
Next is the point that I wish to test if it's been ____ second(s), and if it has, set `madeIron` to false so that iron will again increment.
Everything else in the while-loop is setting fps to a specific amount so that on every computer, the max is the value of fps.
Outside of the while-loop, there's the `stop()` method, which basically stops my game by joining Threads; I don't know how it works, I've just been using it ever since I watched a Youtube tutorial on making games.
**EDIT:**
I just started messing around and I think that a solution might have something to do with if `loops` is a multiple of 5*60 (5 seconds, multiplied by 60 (fps) to get to seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to "generate" Iron or increment any value independently from your main cycle you should make a different thread that increases your values based on the passed time.

Your code looks like your practicing so trying yourself on *multiple threads* with *concurrent* working methods and values might be a good idea. 
The easy and not recommended workaround in your code would be

```
long iTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


if(System.currentTimeMillis - iTime >= (2*1000)) { //2 seconds to milliseconds
      increaseIron();
      iTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

I hope that helped. But try yourself on Threads and [reading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm) this might help.

Comment: Two things: What is inside the `increaseIron()` method, two: where would I put `long iTime`? In the while loop or outside of it.

Comment: @TheMagician increaseIron() could be a `simple Iron += 1;` or a more complex method. Depending on what you want to do. `long iTime` would be defined outside the while loop. the `if(System.currentTimeMillis - iTime >= (2*1000))` needs to be inside of it.